# python function call with variable

Tags: python

```
def test():
    print 'test'

def test2():
    print 'test2'

test = {'test':'blabla','test2':'blabla2'}
for key, val in test.items():
    key() # Here i want to call the function with the key name, how can i do so?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a function of a module from a string with the function's name in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could use the actual function objects themselves as keys, rather than the names of the functions. Functions are first class objects in Python, so it's cleaner and more elegant to use them directly rather than their names.

```
test = {test:'blabla', test2:'blabla2'}

for key, val in test.items():
    key()
```

Answer (score 7):

John has a good solution. Here's another way, using `eval()`:

```
def test():
        print 'test'

def test2():
        print 'test2'

mydict = {'test':'blabla','test2':'blabla2'}
for key, val in mydict.items():
        eval(key+'()')
```

Note that I changed the name of the dictionary to prevent a clash with the name of the `test()` function.

Comment: Oof, not sure why you'd ever use this over the "function objects as keys themselves" method.  If anything, you may be introspecting using something like `hasattr`, but never ever `eval`

Comment: @Daniel I didn't say it was pretty! :D

Comment: This works, but `eval()` has a lot of overhead to use it just calling a function. There's other better, way more "Pythonic" ways...

Comment: ... like, for example, looking up the name in `globals()` and/or `locals()` perhaps? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def test():
    print 'test'

def test2():
    print 'test2'

assign_list=[test,test2]

for i in assign_list:
    i()
```

Comment: in   assign_list     test,test2  give to direct  way i.e [test,test2]

Comment: for i in assign_list:             this  next line        i()

Answer (score -2):

```
def test():
    print 'test'

def test2():
    print 'test2'

func_dict = {
    "test":test,
    "test2":test2
}


test = {'test':'blabla','test2':'blabla2'}
for key, val in test.items():
    func_dict[key]()
```